# Number of $k$ subsets of $S$ by choosing $i$ elements from $A$ and $j$ elements from $B$ where $S=A \cup B$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

Let $A$ be a set with $m$ elements and let $B$ be a set with $n$ elements.

Let $S=A \cup B$. Then the number of $k$-subsets of $S$ is clearly  $C((m+n),k)$.
However, if we want the number of $k$ subsets of $A$ by taking $i$ elements from $A$ and $j$ elements from $B$, I thought the answer was $C(n,i) + C(m,j)$. But my book says the answer is $C(n,i)*C(m,j)$. How is this correct?

For instance if $A=\{1,3,5\}$ and $B = \{2,4,6\}$ and if $i=3$ and $j=2,k=2$, then the number of $2$ subsets of $S$ than can be formed from $\{1,3,5\}$ and $\{2,4\}$ is clearly $C(3,2)+C(2,2)=4$. $(\{1,3\},\{1,5\},\{3,5\},\{2,4\}.)$

Comment: $A$ and $B$ disjoint I expect?

Comment: $i+j=k$ this is not the case in your example.

Comment: For each $i$ element subset of $A$, you can choose any of the $C(m,j)$ subsets of $B$ to obtain a subset of $A \cup B$ with $i$ elements from $A$ and $j$ elements from $B$. Since this procedure applies to any of the $C(n,i)$ subsets of $A$ of size $i$, we get a total of 

$$\overbrace{C(m,j) + \dots + C(m,j)}^{C(n,i) \text{ summands } } = C(n,i) * C(m,j).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably expected to find the number of subsets of $S=A\cup B$ that have $k=i+j$ elements in such a way that $i$ elements come from $A$ and $j$ from$B$.

There are $\binom{m}{i}$ choices for the elements out of $A$ and $\binom{n}{j}$ choices for the elements out of $B$.

So there are: $$\binom{m}{i}\binom{n}{j}$$ choices in total.

Comment: I understand what you wrote, however since we are trying to find the number od k-subsets, shouldnt the final answer involve k somehow? Like in the second para, I wrote that that the total number of k subsets of S is C((m+n),k)

Comment: $k$ is 'present' in the formula as $i+j$. You have $3$ parameters $i,j,k$ together with a relation among them: $i+j=k$. That means that in expressions you have enough on practicizing $2$ of them. In my formula $k$ is left out. If you insist on the presence of $k$ then you can write the formula also as $\binom{m}{i}\binom{n}{k-i}$ or $\binom{m}{k-j}\binom{n}{j}$.

Comment: OK. This may sound silly but why does k have to be equal to i+j? For instance, in my last para, why is it invalid to find the number of 2 element subsets of S by taking 2 elements from A, and 3 elements from B?

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint and you take $2$ elements out of $A$ and $3$ out of $B$ then you automatically end up with a subset of $S=A\cup B$ having $2+3=5$ elements (if you put all elements together).

Comment: Looking at your last paragraph I think you demand wrongly that the $k$-set must be a subset of $A$ **or** a subset of $B$. You are dealing with subsets of $S=A\cup B$ however. A 'part' of the set comes from $A$ (in fact $i$ elements) and a 'part' of it comes from $B$ (in fact $j$ elements). This explains your confusion, and the fact that the book tells you something different.

Answer (score 2):

In the last paragraph you're not doing what you said you wanted to do in the first paragraphs. First, if you want to choose $k$-element subsets by taking $i$ elements from $A$ and $j$ elements from $B$, you need to have $i+j=k$. Second, you didn't write $C(n,i)+C(m,j)$; what you wrote looks more like $C(i,k)+C(j,k)$.

If you do choose $i=3$ elements from $A$ and $j=2$ elements from $B$, then you do get $C(n,i)\cdot C(m,j)=C(3,3)\cdot C(3,2)=1\cdot3=3$ different $5$-element subsets and not $C(n,i)+C(m,j)=C(3,3)+C(3,2)=1+3=4$ as you thought.

More generally, the principle being applied here is the [multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).